# Open & write to console from a C++ DLL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, console

As a quick note before starting my question, I am quite new to C++ and especially DLLs.

I am currently coding a C++ DLL in VS2012, for use with a program. Note that I do not have source access to the specific program.
I'd like to write some output to a seperate console window from the DLL when it gets asked by the program in question to do something.

My question is, how would I go about doing something like this? To clarify exactly what I want, I'd like a seperate console window to open as soon as the DLL gets attached to the program, and have it then write output to the console. When the DLL gets detached from the program it should also close the console window.

My guesses so far have been to make a seperate Win32 console application project in my solution, and then possibly reference it in my DLL, and have it execute certain methods from it, with the output contained in the arguments of the call. I have no idea how to go about this though, especially since I would want this seperate console project to be included in the same DLL.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Well [`AllocConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will get you a console if you don't already have one open. No idea if this works from a DLL though.

Comment: When I did some Google searches on this I did indeed see `AllocConsole` come by, but I have no idea how to implement this in the way I want. (as I said, I am quite new to c++, and the MSDN documentation on this subject is not very extensive)

Comment: Well msdn says `AllocConsole initializes standard input, standard output, and standard error handles for the new console` so you can probably just use `std::cout`. But I've never done this so no idea if it works.

Comment: I wouldn't think you could use cout since it's a DLL.

Comment: Sorry no idea. Someone else will have to help on this ;) I was just guessing at stuff because no one was answering.

Comment: Only one console can be opened per process with AllocConsole. This means that if you try to call AllocConsole in the dll and the calling process already has one, it will fail. Only way I could see this work is if you create a new process in the dll. I'm curious though, why can't you just write to a log file?

Comment: After you call `AllocConsole` just call `freopen` for stdin, stdout, and stderr like so `freopen("conin$", "r", stdin);`. This should take care of all the io.

Answer (score 4):

The following class will give you an idea of what you will need to do.
On construction, a CConsole attempts to use AllocConsole to create a new console for the process.

If AllocConsole fails, nothing is changed -- a console already exists and the class assumes that C-Runtime handles have already been set up somewhere else.

If AllocConsole succeeds, the objects currently associated with stdout and stdin are saved, then these are replaced with ones created for the new console.  Now C-Runtime output functions (like printf) will output to the new console.  cout and cin will also use the new console.

The RemoveMenu call will prevent a user from closing the console window, terminating the process.  It is not necessary beyond this function.

When a CConsole is destroyed (and AllocConsole was successful), stdout and stdin are restored, then the console is closed with a call to FreeConsole.

I find this class to be inconvenient when you want your console to persist beyond the function which created it -- you need to get a new CConsole and keep track of its pointer until you close it with a delete.  But its implementation lays out the steps you will need to take in your own project.  I have never tried this with a dll, but I don't see any reason for this to pose a problem.

Console.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>

class CConsole {
    FILE m_OldStdin, m_OldStdout;
    bool m_OwnConsole;
public:
    CConsole();
    ~CConsole();
};
```

Console.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <FCNTL.H>
#include <io.h>
#include "Console.h"

static BOOL WINAPI MyConsoleCtrlHandler(DWORD dwCtrlEvent) { return dwCtrlEvent == CTRL_C_EVENT;}

CConsole::CConsole() : m_OwnConsole(false) {
    if(!AllocConsole()) return;

    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(MyConsoleCtrlHandler, TRUE);
    RemoveMenu(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), FALSE), SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
    const int in  = _open_osfhandle(INT_PTR(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)),  _O_TEXT);
    const int out = _open_osfhandle(INT_PTR(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)), _O_TEXT);
    m_OldStdin  = *stdin;
    m_OldStdout = *stdout;

    *stdin  = *_fdopen(in,  "r");
    *stdout = *_fdopen(out, "w");

    m_OwnConsole = true;
}

CConsole::~CConsole() {
    if(m_OwnConsole) {
        fclose(stdout);
        fclose(stdin);
        *stdout = m_OldStdout;
        *stdin  = m_OldStdin;
        SetConsoleCtrlHandler(MyConsoleCtrlHandler, FALSE);
        FreeConsole();
    }
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

If you make a seperate console project, you'll get a seperate console application, which may or may not be what you want.  In this case, though, you can make it work, because you can avoid all the mucking about with console handles and just use the app.  You can launch the application from your dll, create a mutex from having more than one instance, and you can have the console application implement a simple logger via named pipes.  Both your dll and your console app open handles to the same named pipe, and you write to the pipe from the dll and read from it in the exe, which writes to stdout.

None of this necessarily requires a console app; you can do this from a GUI app just as easily.   For that matter, as @VoidStar says, you can write to a log directly from the app.  You can also use OutputDebugString and view the output with DebugView from SysInternals.

Comment: It could open a seperate console application, but preferably this would still be compiled in the same DLL - if that is even possible. The console application would still need to be attached to the original program and if the program would terminate the console should terminate as well.

In terms of logging to a file, I was planning to do this also, but I would like a console output for the user. (note - this console question was not really for me debugging - it was for the debugging needed by the user)

Comment: To further elaborate on my comment, the user needs to be able to see what was called by the program to the DLL, and see what the DLL gave back to the program.